# Conditional Expectation Involving Sum of Correlated RVs

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Is it possible to find the $E[X_i | \sum_j X_j \geq c]$ where $c$ is a known constant and the $X_j$ are correlated random variables. $X_i$ is in the $X_j$ terms. I know the correlation matrix between the $X_j$ terms. I can also find the distribution of each of the $X_j$ terms.

Any help or suggestions on how to approach the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you find the distribution of the sum?

Comment: I can find an approximation of the distribution of the sum. It is not a standard distribution (like the normal or anything else). But I do know a relationship between the X_j terms and the sum. So I was thinking I might take the derivative of the total distribution with respect to X_i and then find the value of the derivative at c. So I think this would be the amount that the X_i term contributes to the aggregate at c. If I integrate the derivative multiplied by the probability distribution from c to infinity I think it will work. I am not sure if this logic is accurate though?

Comment: You mean you want to find the Lebesgue density?

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell how to calculate $E(X_i I(\sum_jX_j \geq c))$ if one doesn't know anything about the convolution distribution. In general one could go like this
$$
\int_0^\infty  x_i \int_{c-x_i}^\infty \,dP^{\sum_{j\neq i}X_j |X_i=x_i} \,P^{X_i}(dx_i) = 
\int_0^\infty  x_i P(\sum_{j\neq i}X_j + x_i\geq c\,|\,X_i=x_i) \,P^{X_i}(dx_i)
$$